# Need user input to dictate code

Tags: excel, vba, user-input

I have some code that I found that works perfectly for what I want, which is for an entire sheet to be copied from one workbook to another, but I was hoping to customize it and make it a little bit easier on me (so I don't have to re-code this for all 30 sheets) by allowing the user to specify exactly which sheet they are going to copy.

```
            Sub Start()
            Dim x As Workbook
            Dim y As Workbook

            '## Open both workbooks first:
            Set x = Workbooks.Open("data workbook")
            Set y = Workbooks.Open("destination workbook")

            'This is where I would like the user to input the destination sheet in x:
            x.Sheets("USER INPUT").Range("A1:z28").Copy

            'Then paste data from x to y:
            y.Sheets("STATIC SHEET").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

            'Close x:
            x.Close
            End Sub
```

What I want is for a popup box to appear when the Macro is run that will allow the user to input the name of a sheet (located in "data workbook") to copy the information from, and will automatically enter this input into the Macro when accessing the data to be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has @TyMarc 's answer incorporated into the code you posted but it also has an error handler so that if the user input is not the correct name it will give an error message and ask again.

```
Sub Start()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim x, y As Workbook
    Dim inp as String

    '## Open both workbooks first:
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("data workbook")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("destination workbook")

Label1:

    inp = InputBox("Enter the name of the sheet to be copied")

    'This is where I would like the user to input the destination sheet in x:
    x.Sheets(inp).Range("A1:z28").Copy

    'Then paste data from x to y:
    y.Sheets("STATIC SHEET").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    'Close x:
    x.Close
    Exit Sub 'This is a crutial part otherwise it will finish the program and continue right into the error handler which will send it back to Label1 and start an infinite loop of death...
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox("The input entered was not the name of a worksheet")
    Resume Label1:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you just have to create an InputBox, the result of the InputBox can be stored in a variable, just like this.

```
Dim mySheet As String
mySheet = Application.InputBox("Enter a sheet name")
```

And then put

```
x.Sheets(mySheet).Range("A1:z28").Copy
```

Though you need to make sure the user enters a good sheet name or else you will get an error. Here's my suggestion:

```
Set wsSheet = Sheets(mySheet)
If wsSheet Is Nothing Then
     'prompt the user again
Else
    'put your copy logic here
End If
```

Comment: I did as you said, but when I took a sample name from "data workbook" (I copied the name directly from the workbook to avoid mistyping it) I got a mismatch error.  But when I hit debug it highlights the first line of code ('Set mySheet...').  How can I fix this?

Comment: I think it's a better option to use an `ErrorHandler`. (Look below)